# Using Outlook events with automation

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop

[Using Events with Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866235(v=office.15).aspx) explains how to use Outlook Events with Automation. I don't however understand how to implement that code into my project.

I want to use the `InspectorBeforeMinimizeEvent` method as explained in [Inspector.BeforeMinimize Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868289.aspx)

Whenever the user moves/resizes/maximizes/minimizes the inspector manually then the `MessageBox` should pop up.

Following code is for testing:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

    Public WithEvents myIns As Outlook.Inspector

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Process.Start("Outlook.exe")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application

        Dim myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
        myMailItem = CType(olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
        myMailItem.Subject = "Hello"
        myMailItem.To = "anybody@example.com"
        myMailItem.Body = "Hi there..."

        Dim myIns As Outlook.Inspector
        myIns = myMailItem.GetInspector

        myIns.Display(False)

        Dim myWord As Word.Document
        myWord = CType(myIns.WordEditor, Word.Document)

        Dim mySel As Word.Selection
        mySel = myWord.Application.Selection

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

        'Following line just for testing. Normally following line doesnt exist in my original code. The real scenario is the user minimizes the inspector manually.
        myIns.WindowState = Outlook.OlWindowState.olMinimized

        myWord.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\Example.png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=mySel.GoTo(What:=Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, Which:=Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast, Count:=-4))

        'myMailItem.Send()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Event code:

```
Private Sub myIns_BeforeMinimize(Cancel As Boolean)
     MessageBox.Show("You are minimizing this inspector.", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work you need to add the handler for `Activate` and everytime the `MailItem` is activated you would set the `WindowState`:

```
Private Sub myIns_Activate() Handles myIns.Activate
    myIns.WindowState = Outlook.OlWindowState.olMinimized
End Sub
```

I would also remove these lines:

```
Process.Start("Outlook.exe")
Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

Dim myIns As Outlook.Inspector

Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

You don't need the `Process.Start` as that is handled with `Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application`. You also don't need `Dim myIns As Outlook.Inspector` as that is handled with `Public WithEvents myIns As Outlook.Inspector`. I appreciate the `Threading.Thread.Sleep` lines may be for testing purposes.

Your code would look something similar to this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

    Public WithEvents myIns As Outlook.Inspector

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application

        Dim myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)
        myMailItem.Subject = "Hello"
        myMailItem.To = "anybody@example.com"
        myMailItem.Body = "Hi there..."

        myIns = myMailItem.GetInspector
        myIns.Display(False)

        Dim myWord As Word.Document
        myWord = CType(myIns.WordEditor, Word.Document)

        Dim mySel As Word.Selection
        mySel = myWord.Application.Selection

        myWord.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\Example.png", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=mySel.GoTo(What:=Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine, Which:=Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast, Count:=-4))

        myMailItem.Send()

    End Sub

    Private Sub myIns_Activate() Handles myIns.Activate
        myIns.WindowState = Outlook.OlWindowState.olMinimized
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable for the Inspector object at the class level and set it to the return of the .GetInspector method, then put your code in the actual event:

```
Public WithEvents myIns As Outlook.Inspector

Private Sub myIns_BeforeMinimize(Cancel As Boolean)
     'Your code here
End Sub
```